# mongodb group by date, get the most recent date

Tags: mongodb

I have the following data in my 'payments' collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c2301a31cc7319fcfcc934"),
    "amount" : 243.8016529,
    "payoutDate" : ISODate("2017-09-20T11:20:53.366Z"),     
    "completed" : false,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c24e1bbf0e0520702a9136"),
    "amount" : 243.8016529,
    "payoutDate" : ISODate("2017-09-20T11:20:53.366Z"),
    "shopId" : ObjectId("594cb908554baabc7cbc8e88"),
    "completed" : false,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c24ea1bf0e0520702a915c"),
    "amount" : 1219.0082645,
    "payoutDate" : ISODate("2017-09-21T11:20:53.366Z"),
    "completed" : false,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c24f15bf0e0520702a9216"),
    "amount" : 4876.033058,
    "payoutDate" : ISODate("2017-09-21T11:20:53.366Z"),
    "completed" : false,     
}
```

How can I get get the total amount from payments where `completed = false` for the next day (or today)? So that I get something like this?

```
payoutDate: ISODate("2017-09-20T11:20:53.366Z"),  
totalAmount: 487.6
```

(the `totalAmount` does not have to be rounded)

Edit:

Currently I have this code, but it won't work because error 16006:

> can't convert from BSON type String to Date

But if you can see, my date fields are ISODate already.

```
 Payment.aggregate([
      {"$match": {shopId: shop._id}},
      {
       $project: {
                            year: {$year: "payoutDate"},
                            month: {$month: "payoutDate"},
                            dayOfMonth: {$dayOfMonth: "payoutDate"}
                        }
                    },
                       {$group: {
                            _id: {
                                year: '$year',
                                month: '$month',
                                dayOfMonth: '$dayOfMonth'
                            },
                            totalAmount: {$sum: "$amount"},
                            count: {$sum: 1}
                            }
                        },
                        {$sort: {_id: -1}}
                   ]).exec(function(err, payments){
                       console.log(err, payments);
                   })
```

Comment: Use mongodb aggregation group by - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group

Comment: I have edited my question @titogeo,